# Concatenate arguments using strcpy

Tags: c

I want to concatenate all my arguments into a char pointer using strcpy. I'm doing this but my output is only a space.

I'm using 3 variables: '**concat**' ( which should be my output ) , '**size**' to get the length of all the arguments and '**kar**' which is my iterator for arguments.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int kar;
    int size;
    char *concat;

    kar = 1;
    size = 0;
    //find size to malloc concat
    while (kar < argc)
    {
            size = size + strlen(argv[kar]);
            kar++;
    }
    //malloc size + argc for space characters
    concat = malloc(size + argc);
    kar = 1;
    while (kar < argc)
    {
            strcpy(concat,argv[kar]);
            strcpy(concat," ");
            kar++;
    }
    printf("%s",concat);
}
```

Comment: Try `strcat()` instead of `strcpy()`...

Comment: `malloc(size + argc);` should be `malloc(size + (argc - 1) + 1);` for the `argc-1` spaces characters and the 1 null character - but same end result.  Suggest change in comment.

Comment: @chux I was thinking the exact same thing. Should it be mentioned in an answer? As you say, same end result....

Comment: @FelixPalmen It is that "malloc size + argc for space characters" mis-leads even though `size + argc` is the right size.  IAC, a minor  issue for OP.

Comment: Dont forget to `free` @zeudarius

Comment: thanks so much. it works now. i'm learning programming and i'm not very good. i'll free the memory

Comment: Do you have a problem with for loops?

Comment: @zeudarius you *might* want to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (you don't have to, of course). This gives its author some reputation (and also a little to yourself), but, more importantly, helps future readers to know at a glance that the answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strcpy()` **copies** a string, as implied by the name. So each time you call it, you overwrite your existing string. You are looking for `strcat()`, which concatenates by searching the first `0` byte in the destination and copying there.

You can just replace `strcpy()` by `strcat()` in your code if you initialize `concat[0] = 0;` first.

Answer (score 2):

**strcpy** copies the source's characters into the pointer, as you always use the same address i.e. the start of that string, it keeps overwriting your old string.
It can work if you add an offset by the amount of characters already copied, this way you copy the string properly and get it concatenated

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int kar = 1;
    int size = 0;
    char *concat;

    size_t argl[argc];

    //find size to malloc concat
    while (kar < argc)
    {
            unsigned int arglen = strlen(argv[kar]);
            size += arglen;
            argl[kar] = arglen; // Save the length
            kar++;
    }

    //malloc size + argc for space characters
    concat = malloc(size + argc + 1);
    kar = 1;

    unsigned int offset = 0;
    while (kar < argc)
    {
            strcpy(concat+offset,argv[kar]);
            offset += argl[kar];  // Offset by the length
            strcpy(concat+offset," ");
            offset += 1;
            kar++;
    }
    printf("%s",concat);
}
```

Comment: I **could** see an advantage if you reuse the results from your previous calls to `strlen()` .. but the way you're doing it, it does the same as `strcat()` with just more lines of code.

Comment: I guessed that OP wants to use strcpy for some reason, so I used it. I agree strcat is what is needed here

Comment: looks more likely they just weren't aware of strcat

Comment: @FelixPalmen (and Chris), The code here is carefully avoiding the quadratic behaviour of `strcat()` repeatedly scanning over the leading section of the string to find where the concatenation should occur.  This is  carefully crafted code.  It could be revised to use `memmove()` (or `memcpy()`) instead of `strcpy()`; then the length would be computed before the first copy operation in the loop. It might be tempting to create a VLA `size_t argl[argc];` and initialize the elements of that with the length of each argument in the first loop — saving recomputing the length in the concatenation ops.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler :-) Revisited, now I use array to retrieve values. I'll keep the `strcpy()` for now as OP might want to use it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for pointing this out! I expected exactly what you describe for an optimization (and was indeed thinking about adding something like this to my answer *bevore* this answer was written) .. but I completely missed the fact that this answer *already* saves on quite a lot of scanning. So leaving an upvote here for an optimized approach :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `snprintf()`; it will also work and is easier to use in some situations.

`snprintf(destination, buffer_size, source)` is basically a `strcpy`, and the return value tells you how many bytes were copied.

`snprintf(destination + strlen(destination), buffersize - strlen(destination), new string to add on)`

this does a concatenation but also allows you to insert variables using format `%d`, etc.

Comment: Your second invocation of `snprintf()` flawed.  You should capture the length from the first, add it to the destination, subtract it from the length.  It's important not to use user input as the 'format string'; if the user includes `%d` — or worse, `%n` — in the string, life gets fraught.  You should use something like: `int offset = snprintf(destination, sizeof(destination), "%s", source); offset = snprintf(destination+offset, sizeof(destination)-offset, "%s", extra);` — assuming you can't simply do `snprintf(destination, sizeof(destination), "%s%s", source, extra);` which is still simpler.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for catching that. That was me being lazy. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For starters you should include the header `<stdlib.h>` where the functions `malloc` and `free` are declared.

In general `argc` can be equal to 0. So it is better explicitly to reserve one byte to the terminating zero instead of using the expression `size + argc`.

The function `strcpy` overwrites the previous content of the target string. You should use the function only once when the first command line parameter is being copied. In all other cases you should use standard function `strcat`.

Also you should free the allocated memory before exiting the program.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) n += strlen( argv[i] );

    if ( argc > 1 ) n += argc - 2;

    ++n;

    char *s = malloc( n );

    s[0] = '\0';

    for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        if ( i == 1 )
        {
            strcpy( s, argv[i] );
        }            
        else
        {            
            strcat( s, " " );
            strcat( s, argv[i] );
        }
    }

    puts( s );

    free( s );

    return 0;
}
```

If to specify command line arguments like

```
first second third
```

then the output will be

```
first second third
```